# Codeigniter PHP pulling records from mysql database table to display on page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So it appears I'm in need of some more assistance, I'm trying get records from my database to show on my view page as row descending down for each value but I am just getting HTTP 500 errors not sure where I have went wrong.

ci_users  -  database schema

```
id(PK, int, not null)
user_name(nchar255, not null)
user_email(nchar255, not null)
user_password(nchar255, not null)
user_displayname(nchar255, not null)
user_active(smallint, not null)
user_level(smallint, not null)
```

userlist_view

```
<table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%" border="0">

                <tr bgColor="#a5a6a9">
                    <td width="20%" align="left"><b>User ID</b></td>
                    <td width="20%" align="left"><b>Username</b></td>
                    <td width="20%" align="center"><b>Email Address</b></td>
                    <td width="20%" align="center"><b>Displayname</b></td>
                    <td width="20%" align="center"><b>User Level</b></td>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    foreach ($result as $result) ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $result[0]->id; ?></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $result[0]->user_name; ?></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $result[0]->user_email; ?></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $result[0]->user_displayname; ?></td>
                            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $result[0]->user_level; ?></td>


                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
```

userlist controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class userlist extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('userlist_view');
        }

    function records()
       {
        $data   = array();
        $this->load->model('userlist_database');
        $result = $this->userlist_database->getUsers();
        $this->load->view('userlist_view', $result);
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }

}
?>
```

userlist_database model

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class userlist_database extends CI_Model{

      function __construct()
        {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

    function getUsers() {
        $this->db->select('id','user_name','user_email','user_displayname','user_level');
        $this->db->from('ci_users');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $result = $query->result();

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Missing `</tr>` at the `foreach` loop and improved**

**In Model**

```
function getUsers() {
    $this->db->select('id','user_name','user_email','user_displayname','user_level');
    $this->db->from('ci_users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();

}
```

**In Controller**

```
$data['result'] = $this->userlist_database->getUsers();
$this->load->view('userlist_view', $data);
```

**In View**

```
<?php
    foreach ($result as $item)
    {

        ?>

        <tr>
            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $item['id']; ?></td>
            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $item['user_name']; ?></td>
            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $item['user_email']; ?></td>
            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $item['user_displayname']; ?></td>
            <td width="20%" align="left"><?php echo $item['user_level']; ?></td>

         </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude thats it up and running though I'm getting this little error now

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: user_name

Filename: views/userlist_view.php

Line Number: 100

Comment: @Piglet check DB have filed call `user_name`

Comment: Hey, checked DB and they all have entries in them ..weird, id is there just everything else is not populating

Comment: the field 'id' is the only one displaying data 'user_name' 'user_email' etc have that error message and are not displaying any data

Comment: `print_r($data['result']);die;` add this in controller before view and post the data

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 7 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 8 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 9 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 10 ) [10] => Array ( [id] => 11 ) [11] => Array ( [id] => 12 ) [12] => Array ( [id] => 13 ) [13] => Array ( [id] => 14 ) [14] => Array ( [id] => 15 ) [15] => Array ( [id] => 16 ) [16] => Array ( [id] => 17 ) [17] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [18] => Array ( [id] => 19 ) [19] => Array

Comment: in model change this `$this->db->select(*);`

Comment: seems your table is empty

Comment: two new errors A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/userlist_view.php

Line Number: 91

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/userlist_view.php

Line Number: 91

Comment: your table is empty or you are getting data from wrong tablee

Comment: I queried the table there it has over 30 records in it for all of the fields so I am not sure why its not bringing them up

Comment: post your table images

Comment: I wouldn't be able to post an image due to the sensitive data they contain all I can advise is that it is within a database called clientportal which has 3 tables dbo.ci_sessions dbo.ci_users and dbo.ci_useraccess

Comment: nvm I made a typo in the code its working thanks alot dude!